# What are min_price, max_price, final_price and how are they different from price in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I have been trying to understand these prices changing tax rates, classes, group and tier prices. But all these doesn't change min and max prices in table catalog_product_index_price.

I am actually analyzing catalog/product/price.html to understand in detail how magento handles the prices. I am fully confused on these prices.

Please help me in understanding the mystery behind magento pricing in detail. Also provide me any great tutorials on this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 9):

if you want to get an idea of what the prices mean you need to take a look in the price indexer.
There are 5 price indexers (even more if you are on enterprise) by default depending on the product type.

- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default` for simple and virtual products
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Grouped` - for grouped products
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable` - for configurable products
- `Mage_Bundle_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price` for bundle products
- `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price` for downloadable products

The code may look scary but if you sit down and try to understand eventually you will.

the idea is this.

For simple and virtual products there is no different between price, min_price and max_price. See this code in the default indexer:

```
'price'            => $finalPrice,
'min_price'        => $finalPrice,
'max_price'        => $finalPrice,
```

But for the rest of the product types there may be differences depending on the products that come into play.
The minimum price is the one that you have to pay to get the product with no additional features. Imagine buying a car. You have the standard price when the car has nothing special on it. but by adding features the price increases until you get to the full option price (that's the max price).

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer above there is an excellent article here for understanding how catalog price works. http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-catalog-price-rules/ since you asked for links to the articles that site has a lot of in depth articles on various magento topics.

Comment: FYI, this link is now broken (it's usually better to add the relevant information here in an answer, and include the link for reference, for that reason)

Comment: There's way too much info in the article to repost here, but it is now located at this URL http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-catalog-price-rules/